# Clojure: Why can't I reference class methods without calling them?

Tags: clojure, jvm, lisp, clojure-repl

Here's a Clojure REPL session:

```
moon.core> Double
java.lang.Double
moon.core> (Double/parseDouble "1.0")
1.0
moon.core> Double/parseDouble
CompilerException java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to find static field: parseDouble in class java.lang.Double, compiling:(*cider-repl moon*:1:7159)
```

I'm able to reference `Double`, and I'm able to *call* `Double/parseDouble`, but I can't directly *reference* it. I see the same result for other class methods in the Java standard library (e.g. `Math/abs`, `Integer/parseInt`). the Why is that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't work (in the REPL or otherwise), because there is no static *field* called `parseDouble` on the `Double` class.  `parseDouble` is a method.  You can call it, but you can't access it like a field.

Comment: Interesting. I'm confused by the fact that I can reference (without calling) Clojure functions but not Java methods.

Comment: Yep, Clojure functions and Java methods are entirely different (from an implementation point of view).  IIRC, the ability to automatically generate a Clojure function from a static method was considered, but ultimately rejected for pragmatic reasons.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to turn a static Java method into a Clojure function that you can treat as a first class thing, you can easily wrap a function around it:

```
(def pd #(Double/parseDouble %))
#'user/pd
(pd "1.0")
1.0
```

The `memfn` function can be used to do something like this for Java instance methods.